# How can I make images so that appengine doesn't make transparent into black on resize?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, resize, python-imaging-library

I'm on the google appengine, and trying to resize images. I do :

```
from google.appengine.api import images
image = images.resize(contents, w, h)
```

And for some images I get a nice transparent resize, and others I get a black background.

How can I keep the transparency for all images?

- Original : http://www.stdicon.com/g-flat/application/pgp-encrypted
- Black : http://www.stdicon.com/g-flat/application/pgp-encrypted?size=64
- Original : http://www.stdicon.com/gartoon/application/rtf
- Black : http://www.stdicon.com/gartoon/application/rtf?size=64
- Original : http://www.stdicon.com/nuvola/application/x-debian-package
- Transparent : http://www.stdicon.com/nuvola/application/x-debian-package?size=64

Answer (score 0):

Article on this problem: http://doesnotvalidate.com/2009/resizing-transparent-images-with-django-pil/
Google-code patch: http://code.google.com/p/sorl-thumbnail/issues/detail?id=56

Comment: That looks like a django thumbnail application. Can I use PIL directly on app-engine?

Comment: I've tried, and I can't use PIL in app-engine. Do you have a pure python implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Is this on the dev appserver, or in production? There's a known bug on the dev appserver that turns transparent to black when compositing, but it should run fine in production.

Comment: Production. Dev works perfectly : http://paulisageek.com:4266/gartoon/application/rtf?size=64

Answer (score 0):

With PIL you have to convert your image in RGBA like this :

```
im = im.convert("RGBA")
```

If you want a better implementation, you can read the sorl-thumbnail code. It makes a good usage of PIL.

Comment: I wish I had real PIL on the appengine :(

Comment: The question is why are you using appengine instead of PIL ?
I am quite sure that appengine use PIL so ...

Comment: I don't know what they use underneath, but `import PIL` doesn't work, nor do they expose any function to do what you recommend. (and they won't let me ship them PIL because it has compiled C code)

Comment: On appengine: 

<type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: No module named Imaging
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/openicon/1.337362201776746924/main.py", line 8, in <module>
    import Imaging